# How to make a Woocommerce php plugin that can fetch orders

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, woocommerce

Im building a plugin that has to fetch order data from woo-commerce with authorization using consumer key and consumer secret.

```
<?php

//require_once 'class-wc-api'; 
$consumer_key='consumer_key'; //Consumer Key
$consumer_secret='secret_key'; //Consumer Secret
$Livoni_url='https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders'; //LivoniUrl

//$Livoni_get = file_get_contents($Livoni_url);
//$Livoni_array = json_decode($Livoni_url, true);
//echo $Livoni_array;

curl -X GET 'https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/order';
//$WooCommerce_api = new WooCommerce_API_Client ($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $Livoni_url); //Initialize the class

//$Orders = $WooCommerce_api->get_orders();
//print_r($Orders);

?>
```

this plugin activates but doesnt give me order.
Please Help

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.